# Prove the Identity $\cot x - \frac{1}{2} \sec x \csc x = \cot 2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove the identity $$\cot x - \frac{1}{2} \sec x \csc x = \cot 2x$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry missed something, try now

Comment: You need to use a couple of the better-known trigonometric identities. Double-angle formulae.

Comment: I know but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Start by writing everything in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Get a common denominator for the left hand side.

Comment: @igeer12:  Need to edit your title!

Comment: I got it to $$\frac{2\cos x-2\sin x^22\cos x^2}{2\sin x\cos x}$$ is this correct so far?

Comment: And *voila*!  the title is now correct, thanks!

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for the help mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$cotx - \dfrac{secx\cdot cscx}{2} = \dfrac{cosx}{sinx} - \dfrac{1}{2cosxsinx} = \dfrac{2cos^2x - 1}{2sinxcosx} = \dfrac{cos2x}{sin2x} = cot2x$

Comment: If you put a "\" in front of "cos" etc. you'll get $\cos$, if you like that better than $cos$!

Comment: And +1, since your answer is essentially the same as mine! ;-)

Comment: @RobertLewis: cheerio..

Comment: As Bob Marley said, "nice one"!

Answer (score 1):

Start with

$\cos 2x = 2 \cos^2 x - 1; \tag{1}$

then divide by

$\sin 2x = 2\sin x \cos x; \tag{2}$

you get
$\cot 2x = \dfrac{\cos 2x}{\sin 2x} = \dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x} - \dfrac{1}{2}\csc x \sec x = \cot x - \dfrac{1}{2}\csc x \sec x, \tag{3}$

and there we be!

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***